# How to run Panel data analysis when data on the dependent variable is on a 5 year interval basis and that on independent variable is on yearly basis?

Tags: econometrics, applied-econometrics, regression, paneldata

I am reading a paper which empirically tests if primary exports affect education attainment in LAC countries over the period 1965 to 2010. It uses percentage of secondary school enrollment as dependent variable. It mentions that data has been obtained from Barro and Lee (2013). But the problem is that Barro and Lee provide data for every 5 years 
interval where as the data on primary exports is available on yearly basis. So I'm confused as to how can one perform the regression when the data on one of the variables are largely missing?
I'm using stata to perform the task.

Comment: I would try to find data elsewhere, otherwise maybe consider using a five year average of the independent variable? I doubt you will get meaningful results doing that though. Is there not consistent annual measures of education attainment? I think there would be

Comment: @Brennan I looked up the World Bank, OECD and UNICEF websites but couldn't find yearly data for the LAC countries. And about averaging the independent variables, lag values of GDP andurbanization rate are also there so I'm not sure how averaging them would work out. Besides, as you mentioned, I don't know how that would give meaningful results.

Comment: I am using the same data of Barro-Lee and my independent variables are also on a 5-year basis. How did you solve this issue?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Economics SE. “I have this problem too” answers should be posted as comments instead. Once you earn enough reputation, you’ll be able to post comments on posts.